# How to refer less file in visual studio?

Tags: jquery, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, less

I am new to visual studio. Can anyone tell me that How can I refer `.less` file in my `.cshtml` page.

This is my folder structure in vs

```
/content
   1.css
       1.1. bootstrap.css
   2.Less
       2.1 mixins.less
```

Home.cshtml

```
<head>
     <link href="~/content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Comment: Can't you just drag & drop your file?

Comment: no its just displaying the path `D:\project\Source\Development\project-Beta V1.0\Admin\Content\less\mixins.less`

Comment: I found this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2014/04/29/refactoring-your-css-with-less-in-visual-studio-web-essentials/

Comment: so I should change the extension right?

Comment: apparently. I've never used less myself